# Linear Independence - Vectors in $\Bbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the value(s) of $c$ for which the vectors $(1,0,1,0),(0,1,2,−1), (2, −2, −2, c)$ in $\Bbb{R}^4$ are linearly independent.

To me this seems like a silly question to ask, since there would need to be a pivot in each column of the reduced row matrix. This cannot happen obviously.

Comment: I think you're confused about a theorem. If you're looking at 4 vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ and you form a matrix of them, the vectors are linearly independent if and only if the matrix has a pivot in each column. That's because square matrices are special, however.

Comment: You want a pivot in each column and in each row if you have as many vectors as you have dimensions in the parent dimension.  If you are setting up the vectors as rows, i.e. as $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&2&-1\\2&-2&-2&c\end{bmatrix}$, then you in fact want a pivot in each *row* for them to be linearly independent.  You do not need a pivot in each column.  Alternatively, if you set them up as the columns, then you need a pivot in each column and not one in each row.  The point is that whichever setup you use, you want the matrix to be "*full rank*"

Comment: You don’t really need to go to all the trouble of row-reduction. By inspection, the third vector can’t possibly be a multiple of either of the first two, and there’s only one plausible linear combination of the first two to consider.

Comment: @JMoravitz I was setting up the vectors as columns.

Comment: Then why do you say "this cannot happen obviously" when it certainly *can* and *does* happen for various values of $c$?

Comment: @Jmoravitz I was confused